# How to tell why MagicalRecord update failed

Tags: core-data, magicalrecord-2.2

I am trying to figure out why this failed:

```
    [defaultContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if(success)
        NSLog(@"update successful");
    else
        NSLog(@"update failed: %@", error);
}];
```

I get "update failed" but nil for the error... Where do I start looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you start looking at the repository of issues for MagicalRecord.  I don't use it, but a quick [google search for MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion](https://www.google.com/search?q=MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion) turned up [this known issue](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/464), [and this one](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/838), as hits number 3 and 4.  They look to be relevant, but I didn't check the versions or do anything else.

You wanted a starting place, right ;-).

Comment: I found it... that particular entity didn't exist, so it was nil; and you can't perform save operations on a nil record.  Thank you so much for the 'kick-start'... I appreciate it! :D